# The horizontal scroll bar automatically appears when clicking select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I use select2 and bootstrap. Every time I click select2, my page will expand and appear a horizontal scrollbar.
How to solve this problem:

[image]
[image]

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <select id="js-data-example-ajax" class="js-data-example-ajax form-control" name="parentId"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS Code

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const url = "/ajax/categories";
        $('#js-data-example-ajax').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    const query = {
                        keyword: params.term,
                        page: params.page || 1,
                        limit: 10
                    }
                    return query;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: And what is the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: Have you checked you have proper closing of divs or other tags? It must not be an issue of Select2!

Inspect and check width of div to find out where the width has been added.

Comment: I checked but not found any reagion which with added and not has problem with closing tags.

Comment: Link video description error here: https://youtu.be/VfslJScyPNs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this body{overflow-x:hidden;}

Answer (score 1):

Fix for me with Bootstrap 5.2 was to add `position:relative` to the containing col div.

Bootstrap has a class for it: `position-relative`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 position-relative">
        <select id="js-data-example-ajax" class="js-data-example-ajax form-control" name="parentId"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  The question wasn't how to get rid of horizontal scrolling, it was how to get rid of the horizontal scrolling caused by select2.  This is the way.